# Sumar dos SELECT COUNT(*) de diferentes tablas

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola tengo dos tablas en una base de datos `TABLA_UNO` y `TABLA_DOS`, mi duda es si puedo en una sentencia SQL realizar una suma entre las dos. (Estoy utilizando una base de datos Oracle).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA_UNO --Resultado: 100
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA_DOS --Resultado:310
```

El objetivo sería realizar una sentencia que sume los dos `SELECT COUNT(*)` y de como resultado `410`

¿Se puede realizar aquello con una sentencia SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías unir ambas consultas y sumarlas como subconsulta:

```
SELECT SUM(T.Cantidad)
       FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as Cantidad FROM TABLA_UNO 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT COUNT(*) as Cantidad FROM TABLA_DOS
       ) T
```

Answer (score 1):

Sería así (Oracle no permite una query sin FROM clause, así que se lo tuve que agregar):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA_UNO) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA_DOS) AS total
FROM dual;
```

Otra forma de hacerlo:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM TABLA_UNO 

      UNION ALL

      SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM TABLA_DOS);
```

Comment: Me reclama un ```FROM``` ```ORA-00923: palabra clave FROM no encontrada donde se esperaba```

Comment: Es verdad, nunca había tenido ese problema en las demás bases de datos. Agregale al final `FROM TABLA_UNO`.

Comment: Ahí corregí la primer query y agregué otra query cuyo resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Todas las respuestas funcionaron, jaja no sé con cual quedarme

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select count(*) from tabla1) + (select count(*) from tabla2) as suma from tabla1 
WHERE  ROWNUM < 2
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho des contexto a tu respuesta, por ejemplo ¿por qué esto: `WHERE  ROWNUM < 2`?, checa [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Pude realizar aquello con la siguiente query

```
SELECT SUM(SUMA) AS TOTAL 
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUMA FROM TABLA_UNO UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUMA FROM TABLA_DOS)
```